# How to note that a ticket price is not the final price?

Tags: e-commerce, calendar, price-range

On an e-commerce site we are developing we have a calendar presenting minimum tickets prices, but the final prices will include additional fees.

Our client asked us to add a clear note above the calendar that explains this.

We are proposing:

1. "*Values displayed are just starting price*"
2. "*Starting price available for each day*"

Which one you think it more clear? Is one better than the other?
Do you think that positioning it above the calendar will affect user engagement?

Comment: I'm not sure what the intended meaning is yet. Do ticket prices change over time? Or are you displaying the lowest possible price for the ticket and other charges will be added during checkout? Or something else...?

Comment: We have two condition that change prices for those tickets. First the date of the performance. Second, that will be asked in the next step of the wizard, area of the Theater you would like to seat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're displaying basic ticket prices that will have other charges added before the user pays. If that's the case, then the note could say something like "The prices shown here do not include additional fees." Or "The price you pay will include additional fees." Use a simple sentence structure with clear, unambiguous words.

Users might or might not notice it, depending on how it's presented. (But I usually assume users will skip over any instructional copy.) Another way to add the note is to add an * to every price and add your explanation under the calendar. (People look for footnotes at the bottom.)

Really, though, the more important place to make your extra charges clear is on the checkout page where you must display the price shown, every additional charge, and the total.

Comment: +1, although I believe typically the sentence is even smaller like "additional  fees not included"

Answer (score 0):

Use Amazon.com solution: "starting at $99". 
They also use "from $99" to refer to used items. It is the same case of yours; they can't guarantee that the user will pay that price, they just want to inform how cheap it can get.

Comment: I prefear too this approach but client it not convinced of it

Comment: Did they say why?

Comment: The had already implemented a calendar layout (designed from an other agency) and they do not like the idea of repeating "from" label for each price under the date.